# shell command 'var="[a-p]"; echo $var' has as output "h", any explanation?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, quoting, variable

bash version:

```
$ bash -version
GNU bash, version 4.3.11(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.  
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

command:

```
$ var="[a-p]"; echo $var
h
```

Anyone has an idea what's the reason for this kind of interpretation.

For context I'm parsing a config file using shell and looking for patterns to grab sections names

```
[section-foo]
foo=bar
```

while reading the file, if a section row for example is [a-p] it will get that weird behavior.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a file name `h` in the directory where you ran

```
echo $var
```

The shell tries to use `[a-p]` as a glob, and if anything matches, it replaces the glob with the match. With a file named `h`, that becomes

```
echo h
```

You can prevent this by quoting the expansion, which will cause it to not be treated as a glob.

```
echo "$var"
```

Comment: It's with the echo, not the assignment, that the globbing happens, methinks.

Comment: @Kusalananda it is, and you can confirm that by quoting the expansion.

Answer (score 3):

By not using any quoting in `echo $var` you are exposing the expansion to both "splitting" and "pathname expansion" (aka "globbing" or "filename generation").

That means that a string that contains a `[` (also `*` and `?`) will be expanded by the rules of "pathname expansion". In your case, that means that there is a file with a name of only one character called `h`.

If you quote the expansion, no "Pathname Expansion" will be performed:

```
$ echo "$var"
[a-p]
```